# Remove unwanted whitespace from image of documents

Tags: python

I want to trim off excess whitespace in documents that are scanned copies. Is it possible using python?

I want to remove the unwanted whitespace that is surrounding the text.

This is the sample image before cropping.
https://ibb.co/BVVZwDb

This is after cropping.
https://ibb.co/PGy4mdd

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an OCR for this type of job.

A possible solution to test: [Tesseract OCR with Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/)

*an OCR is an application which transforms an image to Text

Comment: No, I just want to crop it. I don't want to extract text from it.

Comment: then that depends of your scanner, some can cut the image in multiple parts and rebuild following a logic...

Comment: Like CamScanner, I want to create a border around the text area and then chop off the rest. Is it possible to find the boundaries of text and mark a border around it?